# Where can I find WidgetRedirector in with Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I was using a tkform(https://github.com/boscoh/tkform) with Python2 and it was working perfectly.
After switching to Python3, Im unable to run it, specifically the part:

```
from idlelib.WidgetRedirector import WidgetRedirector
```

It seems that WidgetRedirecor.py not even in the library (idellib) anymore...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/igor/opt/cymorph3/runCyMorphGUI.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tkform
  File "gui/tkform.py", line 22, in <module>
    from idlelib import WidgetRedirector
ImportError: cannot import name 'WidgetRedirector' from 'idlelib' (/Users/igor/opt/anaconda3/envs/cyMorph3/lib/python3.9/idlelib/__init__.py)
```

Can I fix it somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```py
from idlelib.redirector import WidgetRedirector
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @IgorKolesnikov Btw I just opened my python installation folder and it was under `Lib.idlelib.redirector`.

Comment: Yeah, I looked there, and now the file called redirector.py (which contains WidgetRedirector class.)